# Tibet: Safe for Traveling?

Tags: safety, tibet

I think that there is a general consensus that Tibet is unsafe for traveling. I somehow feel, though, that the majority of people who *claim* Tibet is unsafe are either somewhat prejudiced (Han minorities) or exploitative (Fox News readers) and don't really have much of a basis for claiming such things.

What's the deal? Is Tibet safe for traveling or not?

Comment: Who says random (almost) anonymous people on this site (myself included, of course) aren't disguised Han Fox News readers? (Do people *read* Fox News btw?)

Comment: Where is this "general consensus" coming from? People who have never visited China?

Comment: I think there are people whose job is to provide you with safety information regarding a country you might visit. It is the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of your country (or others), that usually publishes advice on what country/area to avoid. I would recommend you to check their website instead of asking random people.

Comment: Woo, Fox News! ;)

Comment: The problem I found, with the US Dept. of State, is that there is no guidance (official) separate from China.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realistically, assuming you can get permission to visit Tibet (the permission for which is separate from the rest of China), the most dangerous part of a visit by a Westerner seems to be the actual flight into Lhasa Gonggar airport.

This is recognized by many pilots as one of the most dangerous landings in the world. Please note that there haven't been more accidents than 'normal,' it is just a very difficult landing which requires special training and only those pilots who are especially licensed for the airport are allowed to land at it.

Crime against tourists in Tibet is almost wholly unheard of. There are the sorts of petty crimes that occur anywhere in the world, such as pick-pocketing at the markets, but by and large, tourists are not subjected to it.

Enjoy your trip to the top of the world, and know that you've gone to a place most of us have never or could never go!